# Title bar not showing an Image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written a code for showing Image and Text in title bar. Text is showing, but not the Image.

Here is layout_my_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/bv_title_string"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Here is styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="customTitleBackground">
            <item name="android:background">@color/titlebackgroundcolor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here is themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/customTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: What is this @style/customTitleBackground ?

Comment: It is a background color for the title bar

Comment: @PratikSharma Not still. I am trying.

Comment: @Dhwani where you are using this `style` called `customTheme`?

Comment: @PratikSharma, in manifest file. <application
        android:theme="@style/customTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">  I want to use it for all Activities.

Comment: @Dhwani it is working for me. I can have `image + text` on the `titlebar` with this `custom theme`.

Comment: @PratikSharma: I dont know why I am not able to see the Image. My minimum SDK version is 9. Is that a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21990/discussion-between-pratik-sharma-and-dhwani)

Answer (score 0):

- Create custom layout for window title in “layout” folder.

`window_title.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout
>      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      android:orientation="horizontal"
>      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="35dip"
>     android:gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:paddingLeft="5dip"
>      android:background="#323331"> 
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/header"
>     android:src="@drawable/header"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

- Create custom style in “values” folder.

`custom_style.xml`

> ```
>   <resources>        
>   <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
>     <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
>   </style>
>   <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
>     <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
>     <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
> </style>
> ```

- Apply custom style in manifest file as theme.
  `AndroidManifest.xml`

> ```
> <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
> ```

- Apply custom window title in main activity class
  `CustomWindowTitle.xml`

> ```
> public class CustomWindowTitle extends Activity {
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
>     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); 
>     setContentView(R.layout.main); 
>     getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
> }   }
> ```

i hope this will help you out.

Comment: I want Image + Text. Not only Image.